# CSS transition to effect JUST box-shadow colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to limit CSS' `transition` to just target a box-shadow's colour, and nothing else?

For example, you have a button with a box shadow. When you click the button it moves downwards and the box shadow shrinks, to make it seem as if the button has compressed. [See this example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_animate3).

But - I also want the button to be able to change colour, and I want this effect to be transitioned. I can do so with something like this:

```
#button {
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
}
```

My problem is this transition also occurs when the button is pressed and not just when the color changes. This means the box shadow slowly shrinks, while the button moves down instantly. [See this example](https://jsfiddle.net/tn1gx50h/). I want the press and movement of the button to be instantaneous, and not transitioned, so **is it possible for CSS's `transition: box shadow` property to only effect the box shadow's color?**

If not, is there any other method I could try? Perhaps with jQuery? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your example? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I read twice and still don't understand either. Not very clear.

Comment: See the two examples I have linked. The first is my button, and the second is an example of how the `transition: box-shadow` causes the shadow to move downwards slowly on click, and not instantly with the rest of the button. The `transition: box-shadow` is necessary because I want the button to transition between colours for a smooth look. @dfsq

Comment: See above comment @Tymek

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. It would also be great if you could accept and/or upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can animate only the shadow color, though you need a little trick, using a pseudo element `::after` being the actual green button and then set the shadow on the button itself.

This way you will be able to move the "button" alone, and at the same time animate only the shadow. In below sample I chose to animate it to red so it's easy to see it work.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  transition: box-shadow 1s linear;
  background: transparent;
}
.button::after {
  content: attr(data-buttontext);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 9px #f00;
}
.button:active::after {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<button class="button" data-buttontext="Example"></button>
```

Comment: Very clear and easy to understand, thanks @Ason